# Pointer with and without brackets

Tags: c, pointers

1st:
`p = (int *)sp` VS `p = int *sp` VS `p = int (*sp)`

2nd:
`(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node))` VS `struct node* malloc(sizeof(struct node))`
VS `struct node (*malloc(sizeof(struct node)))`

3rd:
`#define cEEP_ABC  *((CHAR *)ps8c_PROM( EEP_TEST+0x2B ))`

What is the difference for the statement in 1st and 2nd question?

For 3rd question, `*((CHAR *)ps8c_PROM( EEP_TEST+0x564 ))`

```
             ^      ^ 
             |      |
             |      |
             |      |
              ---------------- What the purpose for these 2 pointer?
```

Can the statement change to this form: `*(CHAR *ps8c_PROM( EEP_TEST+0x2B )) or *(CHAR (*ps8c_PROM( EEP_TEST+0x2B )))`?

Comment: for first question to the compiler, there is no difference between the these declarations.

Comment: You should remove the leading and trailing `**`s.

Answer (score 0):

**1st**:

```
p = (int *)sp; //typecasting sp to int* and storing it in p
p = int *sp; //Declares sp as int* and its value is stored in p
p = int (*sp); //Compilation error
```

**2nd**:

```
(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Allocates memory equal to size to struct node and returns a pointer to the start

Others: Compilation error.
```

**3rd**:

`(CHAR *)ps8c_PROM( EEP_TEST+0x564 )` typecasts the return value of the function to `char *` and the leading `*` gives the value pointed by that address. So it returns a `char`.